# Windows 10 energy saving mode without power

Tags: windows-10, energy-saving

Until a recent Windows 10 update I have been used to putting my PC into energy saving mode instead of shuting it down. This was to keep all the opened programs and not having to open everything again on the next startup. When my PC had completed the energy savings mode I would then turn off the power.
On the next start it would then take a little longer to boot in comparison to continuously having the power supply turned on, but it would correctly continue from where I had put it in energy saving mode.

Now, after that recent windows update I enable energy saving mode, turn of the power and on next startup it is like I had done a normal shutdown. No restored session, everything closed, just a fresh boot without any error message.

Now my question is: **Why does my Windows 10 no longer restore my session when I turn off power while in energy saving mode?**

Comment: You relied on Hibernate being part of Hybrid Sleep before. Did you perhaps turn it off at some point?

Comment: ^ This. Also, do you have sufficient disk space for a hibernate .sys file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the direction that Daniel B gave I was able to fix my problem.

Issuing `powercfg /a` via CMD I was told that my hypervisor does not support Hybrid Sleep. This did stem from me recently enabling CPU-virtualization in the BIOS. After disabling it I'm able to use Hybrid Sleep again.

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! Would have never been able to solve it otherwise.